# Memory copying NASM x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to do a simple operation on some bytes with nasm.

The idea is: I have a global array of zeros (seen), and a pointer to a location in memory (seed) where there is some integer value (1001, as an example).

I want to copy the value at seed into the array seen, and then display it.

```
section .bss ; declare variable arrays
 _bss_start:
   seed resq 1 
   seen resq 100
 _bss_end:

section .text ; code section
  global _start
_start:
  mov dword [seed], 1001
  mov dword [seen], seed ;[seed], dword [seed] all different to 1001
  mov ebx, [seen]
  mov eax, 1 
  int 0x80
```

however I must be doing something wrong as [seed], seed and dword [seed] all produce different results to the raw 1001.

What is wrong here?

Comment: You're storing the address of `seed` as an immediate constant.  x86 can't `mov` from mem to mem so you'll need to load into a register and then store.

Comment: @PeterCordes ... yep fair enough, but then I lose some information for values above 256 right?

Comment: No, registers like EAX are 32-bit, not 8.  (Or 64-bit in 64-bit mode for RAX).  If you're in 32-bit mode, copying a qword takes 2 integer registers for the low and high halves, or `fild` / `fistp`, or MMX or SSE `movq`.

Comment: ah I see, thank you then!

Comment: Don't edit the answer into the question.  Post an answer if you want.  But note that you're only copying the low dword of the qword you reserved so you might want to change to `resd`.

Comment: right, so change to `seed resd` ?